# Must all Lebesgue integrable functions really be invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, notation, inverse

I am studying Lebesgue integration after a course on Riemann integration, and the definition of measurable function is given as follows:

> $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is measurable if the pre-image $f^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is measurable for each $a\in {\mathbb R}.$

So this necessarily implies that a function would not be Lebesgue integrable if it does not have an inverse, since it would not be measurable.

But I don't recall this restriction for Riemann integrals. Or was it just implicitly assumed that every Riemann integrable function is invertible?

Comment: You are absolutely right. While all functions you will think of (unless you have very advanced thoughts/phantasies for someone who is seeing the definition of measurable functions for the first time!) will be measurable, it is really easy for you to come up with a method $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which does not have an inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ here does not mean the inverse of $f$. It is a horrifically bad overuse of notation and can be very misleading. $f^{-1}(A)$ where $A$ is a set is the pre-image, i.e.

$$f^{-1}(A) = \{x\in X: f(x) \in A\}.$$

The pre-image always exists. If $f$ were invertible, then this would coincide with what you think; however the pre-image takes care of the multi-valued aspect.

Take for instance $f:[-1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$. This is  not invertible as you can see by, e.g., $f(-1) = 1 = f(1)$. However

$$f^{-1}([0,1]) = \{x\in [-1,2]:f(x) \in[0,1]\}.$$

The set of $x$ that solve this are those $x$ in $[-1,1]$ since when you square them you get something in $[0,1]$.

This function is not invertible but it is continuous on a set of finite Lebesgue measure, hence Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: "Just like that. A whopper of a puzzle piece falls smack in my lap."

Comment: By the way, you should accept one of the answers to this question if you feel they have appropriately answered your question! I see that you don't accept a lot of answers to your questions. This is a bad habit and can leave people with the feeling that they're being used. Moreover, questions with no accepted answers will be bumped by Community from time to time.

Comment: @FemaleTank Just making sure you get a notification for Cameron Williams's comment about accepting answers.

Comment: @Kyle: If only one other user besides the author has commented on a post, [they will be automatically notified when the author posts a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts), even if there's no `@user` tag. So your making sure, though surely well meant, was actually unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ah, thanks. I'd been wondering what the exact conditions were for those notifications.

Answer (score 19):

$f^{-1}(A)$ is the **preimage** of the set $A$, it exists even if $f$ is not invertible. For $f: X\to Y$, it is defined as

$$f^{-1}(A) = \{x\in X: f(x)\in A\}.$$

The notation is slightly confusing, I would say, but one gets used to it. It isn't really that bad of a notation, since, if $f$ is actually invertible and its inverse is $g$, then $g(A) = f^{-1}(A)$ (so the *preimage* of $A$ according to $f$ is the *image* of $A$ according to $f^{-1}$).

Answer (score 3):

For any function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, the set $f^{-1}( a, \infty)$ always exists, and it is defined by $$ \{ x: \in \mathbb R : f(x) > a \}, $$ although it is not always measurable.